# Outer with non-diagonal elements

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a way to perform `Outer` operation without evaluating diagonal elements like:

`Outer[f, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}]`, expecting the following output:

`{{f[1, 2], f[1, 3]}, {f[2, 1], f[2, 3]}, {f[3, 1], f[3, 2]}}`?

Shold I put condition on the function `f`?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Outer[If[# == #2, ## &[], f@##] &, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

> {{f[1, 2], f[1, 3]}, {f[2, 1], f[2, 3]}, {f[3, 1], f[3, 2]}}

Also

```
Array[If[# == #2, ## &[], f@##] &, {3, 3}]
```

> {{f[1, 2], f[1, 3]}, {f[2, 1], f[2, 3]}, {f[3, 1], f[3, 2]}}

**Note:** You can also use `Unevaluated @ Sequence` and, in versions 10+, `Nothing` in place of `##&[]`.

**Update:** An alternative to post-processing suggested by VitaliyKaurov is to re-define `f` to give `Nothing` for equal arguments (`f[x_,x_]:=Nothing`) before using it in `Outer`:

```
res1 = Block[{g = f}, g[x_,x_]:=Nothing;Outer[g, Range[10^3], Range[10^3]]  ]; // 
    RepeatedTiming  // First
```

> 0.56

```
res2 = Replace[Outer[f, Range[10^3], Range[10^3]], _[x_, x_] -> Nothing, {2}]; // 
    RepeatedTiming// First
```

> 0.704

```
res1 == res2
```

> True

Comment: `Nothing` instead of `## &[]` would work too.

Comment: Thank you @Vitaliy; added that variation.

Comment: `Block[{g = f}, g[x_, x_] :=...]` sets a value for `f[x_, x_] :=...` (because the head of the LHS is evaluated first inside `SetDelayed`). Strangely ``Block[{f}, f[x_, x_] :=...]`` adds significant running time, although it seems equivalent to blocking `g`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, good point. I am puzzled too.

Comment: As this was accepted I assume it's fine, but maybe as a note to future readers: This does*not* remove the diagonal from the output. It removes any elements where the arguments are the same, which might not be the same depending on the second and third argument of `Outer`.

Answer (score 8):

[`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) and [`Drop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Drop.html) removes the diagonal:

```
MapIndexed[Drop, Outer[f, Range[3], Range[3]]]
(*  {{f[1, 2], f[1, 3]}, {f[2, 1], f[2, 3]}, {f[3, 1], f[3, 2]}}  *)
```

It removes the diagonal of any square array, for instance, if the array is generated with an `f` that is already defined or is a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html):

```
MapIndexed[Drop, Outer[10 #1 + #2 &, Range[3], Range[3]]]
(*  {{12, 13}, {21, 23}, {31, 32}}  *)
```

It can be used in the operator form `MapIndexed[Drop] @ Outer[..]`.

It's faster than replacing diagonal elements or defining `f[x, x]` to evaluate to `Nothing`.

```
res1 = Block[{g = f},
     g[x_, x_] := Nothing; 
     Outer[g, Range[10^3], Range[10^3]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(*  0.42  *)

Clear[f];  (* needed if res1 is evaluated before res2 *)
res2 = Outer[f, Range[10^3], Range[10^3]], _[x_, x_] -> Nothing, {2}]; //
  RepeatedTiming // First
(*  0.43  *)

res3 = MapIndexed[Drop, Outer[f, Range[10^3], Range[10^3]]]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
(*  0.199  *)

res1 === res2 === res3
(*  True  *)
```

Most of the time for the `Drop` method is spent generating the array:

```
Outer[f, Range[10^3], Range[10^3]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(*  0.184  *)
```

Note: The current method of using `Block[{g = f},...]` still defines a value for `f[x_, x_]`, since `g` evaluates to `f` in `SetDelayed`.  Failing to clear `f` before running `res2` adds about 50% to the execution time (0.61s).  Using `Block[{f}, f[x_, x_] :=...]` takes about 25% longer (0.506s).

Answer (score 7):

Because operation on diagonal elements is performed anyways you could take an alternative path of removing them post-evaluation. You should ask a question what time is spent on the special construct removing diagonal during evaluation? Perhaps an alternative post-removal would be faster.

```
Replace[Outer[f, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}], _[x_, x_] -> Nothing, {2}]
```

Timing measures:

```
Replace[Outer[f, Range[10^3], Range[10^3]], _[x_, x_] -> Nothing, {2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.528235`, Null}

```
Outer[If[# == #2, Nothing, f@##] &, Range[10^3], Range[10^3]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.313204`, Null}

```
Array[If[# == #2, Nothing, f@##] &, {10^3, 10^3}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.41581`, Null}